# How do I share my mobile internet connection in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: internet

I've a blackberry that I connect to the internet through barry application, can this connection be shared somehow? I use a old laptop that don't have a build in wifi. I can't use a wifi usb adapter as there aren't support for netgear WNA3100 device.

Comment: Uh... so then what *does* it have?

Comment: It does a normal network adapter for network cabeling. My normal DSL is down until they fix it. I have to use a blackberry to have internet access.

Comment: So then an Ethernet connection?

Comment: yes. I use now a usb connected blackberry while I wait for my DSL to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to get the wifi usb adapter to work with ndiswraper? most easy should be to use ndisgtk.

with my android phone I can connect to my wireless and than tether over usb. [this article](http://nearlydeaf.com/?p=345) claims to describe how to do it with blackbarry, but I can not try it. it is a old post and most of the links are dead, but the [berry4all](http://www.berry4all.com/home) site is still up.

Comment: How do I use ndiswrapper? I tried to use it before, but without success.

Comment: Yea it has been a while since I had to use it. What you do is you install ndisgtk via the software center. Now to add the driver you need a .inf file. I could not find it on the netgear site (it won't let me download anything without a serial number. But I found [this page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Netgear_WNA3100). it has a .zip with a .inf file in it extract it someware. Open ndisgtk (Windows wireless drivers) and click  `add new driver` and brows to the inf file and select it.

Comment: if that dousn't work you can also try to read trough the page and try to set it up from the terminal.